# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure n?

Tags: java, docker, spring-ws, rancher

I have a keystore with a valid certificate. I include it programatically. works fine on my local machine. but after creating a docker image and deploying it on rancher i get a handshakeException. I have no idea why am i getting this error. i can see the keystore gets loaded on start up. This is what i have in my code:

```
    val ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS")
    ks.load(FileInputStream(ResourceUtils.getFile(config.keyStore)), 
    config.keyStorePassword.toCharArray())

    val keyManagerFactory: KeyManagerFactory = 
    KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())
    keyManagerFactory.init(ks, config.keyStorePassword.toCharArray())
    val messageSender = HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender()
    messageSender.setKeyManagers(keyManagerFactory.keyManagers)
    myBean.setMessageSender(messageSender)
```

I use webserviceTemplate. I also tried using rancher secret instead of programatically including the cert in the code, I get the same error. I am just confused now as of what is it that i am doing wrong. please help

Comment: Do you use same Java (virtual mashine) version on host mashine and docker image ?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. yes,  the version is openjdk version 11.0.6.

Comment: I have fixed my own problem. I was not configuring a trust manager.  Not sure why was it working on my local host without the trust manager configuration.